# Janus Vim : Remap Command-Shift-F to git grep

Tags: vim, grep, janus

I've found this git grep vim plugin but I can't figure out how to map my Command-Shift-F to invoke it. I have already disabled the Ack plugin that comes by default.

https://github.com/tjennings/git-grep-vim/

Answer (score 2):

You only need to create a custom mapping that calls the `GitGrep` command:

```
nnoremap <D-S-f> :GitGrep<Space>
```

After that, hitting `<D-S-f>` will put

```
:GitGrep | <-- cursor here
```

in the command-line, ready to take arguments.

But I'd advise you to choose a better shortcut: `<D-S-f>` works only in MacVim. Even there, I seem to remember that key combos like this one didn't really *work*. MacVim didn't complain but `<D-S-f>` was somehow the same as `<D-f>`. IIRC, you have to map `<D-F>` instead of `<D-S-f>`.

Something like `,f` would be more appropriate, I believe, and more portable.

Answer (score 0):

Janus already includes the absolutely awesome [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive), which provides the `:Ggrep` command as well.

So, we can just hack the way [Janus adds mapping for Ack](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/janus/vim/tools/janus/after/plugin/ack.vim).

First disable the `Ack` plugin in your `~/.vimrc.before` like so:

`call janus#disable_plugin('ack')`

Then in your `~/.vimrc.after` just append the following code:

```
if has("gui_macvim") && has("gui_running")
  " Command-Shift-F on OSX
  call janus#add_mapping('ggrep', 'map', '', ':Ggrep')
else
  " Define  to a dummy value to see if it would set  as well.
  map  :dummy

  if maparg("") == ":dummy"
    " f on systems where  == 
    call janus#add_mapping('ggrep', 'map', 'f', ':Ggrep')
  else
    "  if we can still map  to 
    call janus#add_mapping('ggrep', 'map', '', ':Ggrep')
  endif

  map  
endif
```

Enjoy!